# How to add Hybrid Suspend to Shutdown menu?

Tags: suspend, systemd

If I want to put my PC to hybrid suspend I use this command:

```
systemctl hybrid-sleep
```

But is there convenient way to add this shortcut to shutdown menu alongside with regular shutdown and reboot options?